# No se envian los datos del formulario de una ventana modal

Tags: php, html

Tengo una pagina con un formulario (llamado frmNuevo) para registrar un producto el cual si envía y guarda la información correctamente el la db y con ese no tengo ningún problema, y tengo un botón dentro del primer formulario el cual abre una ventana modal la cual contiene otro formulario (llamado frmUmedida) con dos campos y un botón que tendría que guardar la información en la db el problema es que al hacer click no envía la información y no se por que, el código de la pagina pagina es...

```
<?php
    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Controller/controllerReactivo.php");
    $controllerReactivo = new controllerReactivo();

    include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/Controller/controllerUmedida.php");
    $controllerUmedida = new controllerUmedida();
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reactivos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-new-reactivo.css">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <?php include('menu.php'); ?>  
    </header>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
        <div class="popup" id="popup">
            <div class="popup-title">
                <h3 class="title">Registrar unidad de medida</h3>
                <a href="" class="btn-cerrar-popup" id="btn-cerrar-popup"><span id="log-close" class="fa fa-close" title="Cerrar"></span></a>
            </div>
            <form id="frmUmedida" name="frmUmedida">
                <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                    <label for="txtMedida">Unidad de medida:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMedida" name="txtMedida" placeholder="Unidad de medida" required>
                    <label for="txtDescription">Descripcion</label>
                    <textarea type="text"  class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion" name="txtDescripcion" placeholder="Descripcion" rows="3"></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" value="submit">
                    Guardar
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<img src="../img/reactivos.jpg" alt="reactivo" class="col-lg-12 imgprincipal">
<div class="container">
    <form id="frmNuevo" name="frmNuevo"> 
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <label for="id_reactivo">Reactivo:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="id_reactivo" name="id_reactivo">
                    <?php
                        $controllerReactivo->opcionesReactivo();
                    ?>                           
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="txtcontenido"> Contenido:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcontenido" name="txtcontenido">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <label for="txtumedida">Unidad de medida:</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="txtumedida" name="txtumedida">
                    <?php
                        $controllerReactivo->opcionesUmedida();
                    ?>                           
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1">
                <button type="button" class="fa fa-plus btn-abrir-popup" id="btn-abrir-popup"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="txtcantidad">Cantidad:</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="txtcantidad" name="txtcantidad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="txtfechaentrada">Fecha de entrada:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtfechaentrada" name="txtfechaentrada">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <label for="txtfechavencimiento">Fecha de vencimiento:</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="txtfechavencimiento" name="txtfechavencimiento">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-12 botones">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnavance" name="btnavance">
                    Guardar Reactivo
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btnCancelar" id="btncancelar" name="btncancelar " >
                    Cancelar
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

en el mismo archivo tengo el codigo javascript

```
<script src="../js/main-popups.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrapvalidator.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#frmNuevo").bootstrapValidator(
            {
              feedbackIcons:
              {
                  valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                  invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                  validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
              },
              fields:{
                id_reactivo:{
                    validators:{
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'El campo es obligatorio.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                txtcontenido: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'El campo es obligatorio.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                txtfechavencimiento: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'El campo es obligatorio.'
                        }
                    }
                },
                txtcantidad: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'El campo es obligatorio.'
                        }
                    }
                }
              }
            }).on('success.form.bv', function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                //alert("ERROR");
                agregarReactivo();
            });

            $("#frmUmedida").bootstrapValidator({
            feedbackIcons:
            {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields:{
                txtMedida:{
                    validators:{
                        notEmpty:{
                            message: 'El campo es obligatorio.'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).on('success.form.bv',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //alert("ERROR");
            agregarUmedida();
        })
    });

function agregarReactivo() {
            $.post("../Controller/controllerReactivo.php",
                  { operacion:'agregarReactivo',
                    id_reactivo:$("#id_reactivo").val(),
                    contenido:$("#txtcontenido").val(),
                    umedida:$("#txtumedida").val(),
                    cantidad:$("#txtcantidad").val(),
                    fechaEntrada:$("#txtfechaentrada").val(),
                    fechaVencimiento:$("#txtfechavencimiento").val()
            },function(data){
            if(data.success == true){
                alert("Operacion Exitosa");
            }else{
                alert("Ha ocurrido un error. Comunicate con el encargado.")
            }
        },"json");
            //alert("error");
        }

        function agregarUmedida() {
            $.post("../Controller/controllerReactivo.php",
            { operacion:'agregarUmedida',
                medida:$('#txtMedida').val(),
                descripcion:$('#txtDescripcion').val()
            },function(data){
                if (data.success == true) {
                    alert("Unidad de medida agregada.");
                } else {
                    alert("Ha ocurrido un error. Comunicate con el encargado.");
                }
            },"json");
            //alert("error")
        }
</script>
```

al dar click para guardar la imformacion de la ventana modal no pasa nada estuve checando en el inspector de codigo para ver la red y las respuestas y no manda nada

Answer (score 0):

Hola creo que te hace falta el atributo action en la etiqueta form

```
<form method="POST" action="php/registration.php" class="register-form" id="register-form">
```

ya en el archivo registration.php ya es la accion que va a ejecutar el formulario si lo guarda enuna BD o mandarlo en un Email.